# How to get rid of "Build input file cannot be found" and "No such file or directory"?

Tags: ios, xcode

These are the only errors that appear when I'm trying to build and run the project and appears on both simulator and real iPhone device. There is a simple app with 4 view controllers. If you need any additional information, let me know.

This is the required information you should know:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Clearly your project is trying to reference some non-existent files in your project. Make sure the files actually exist or remove their references.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode is trying to access file note1.wav which not present in your project. Search for this file in your project and remove the reference or add the actual file to the project, clean and build should work fine.